# Why is the list element in the navigation sidebar not being styled?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a rudimentary sidebar, and this is my first attempt at it:

```css
body {
font-family: courier;
font-size: 18px;
    }

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.side {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: grey;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 10px;

#nav {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>Test Page For Fixed Sidebar</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Information</h1>
      <p> To your left is a sidebar containing links </p>
      <div class="side">
          <ul id="nav">
              <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

I seem to have a problem with styling the navigation sidebar, i.e. the element `ul id=nav`. I am trying to change the list's bullets to squares, and have even tried to remove them completely, but any changes to the corresponding stylesheet are not reflected on the page. I am able to style other elements it just seems to be this one which is causing me a problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target list items using class or id, you will have to target the li within the navigation bar. This is done by doing this

```
/* targeting the #nav and then looking for li tags withing it */
#nav > li
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either, unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the trouble you're having?

Comment: I'm attempting to target the elements in that list using what you just said, it doesn't have an effect. Does it work for you?

Comment: It's weird because when i'm using an internal style sheet like yours everything works fine, but when I use an external one I encounter the same problem.. any solution?

Comment: Try adding 'type="text/css"' into your link tag. such as <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" /> Not sure if that makes any diffrence but try it